# Filtering for a set of files that start and end with certain characters

Tags: bash, find, wildcards

Hi I am new to all of this so any help is appreciated!! 
I have a list of files that I want my bash script to work on such as

BG2_45TS02.assembled.fast

BG2_45TS02.riboassembled.fastq

BG3_45TS02.assembled.fastq

BG3_45TS02.riboassembled.fastq

BG4_45TS02.assembled.fastq

BG4_45TS02.riboassembled.fastq

If I only want to pick out those starting with BG2 and those ending with .riboassembled.fastq

does this work BG2*.riboassembledfastq
 so for example my script would be

```
for file in $STEP_2/BG2*.riboassembled.fastq
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work.

You can simply try with using `echo` or `printf` in your loop:

```
$ for file in "$STEP_2"/BG2*.riboassembled.fastq; do printf '%s\n' "$file"; done
/BG2*.riboassembled.fastq
```

Search for `globbing` to get more information and tutorials on how it works, e.g. https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Note, variables containing file names (here `$STEP_2`) should be put in double quotes, otherwise it will cause problems if the variable contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

As pLumo suggested, you could use `$file` variable to point at your current file

Run:

```
$ for file in ./BG2*; do cat $file; done
```

Result:

```
./BG2_45TS02.assembled.fast
date
Wed 04 Mar 2020 02:39:39 PM EET
./BG2_45TS02.riboassembled.fastq
date
Wed 04 Mar 2020 02:39:39 PM EET
```

Run:

```
$ for file in ./BG2*ribo*q; do cat $file; done
```

Result:

```
./BG2_45TS02.riboassembled.fastq
date
Wed 04 Mar 2020 02:39:39 PM EET
```

Instead of `do cat $file` you could use something else. `cat $file` is only for demonstration.